# Is it possible to apply function over one stack of rasters and change values in another

Tags: r, raster, terra

lets say we have 3 raster stacks as follow:

```
library(terra)

r <- rast(ncols=2, nrows=2)

r1 <- setValues(r, c(0.7,0.2,0.5,0.9))
r2 <- setValues(r, c(0.6,0.18,0.3,0.7))
r3 <- setValues(r, c(0.3,0.24,0.2,0.1))
r4 <- setValues(r, c(0.18,0.4,0.3,0.3))
r5 <- setValues(r, c(0.3,0.5,0.35,0.4))
r6 <- setValues(r, c(0.5,0.6,0.7,0.6))
r7 <- setValues(r, c(0.8,0.9,0.8,0.8))
r8 <- setValues(r, c(0.7,0.7,0.5,0.6))
r9 <- setValues(r, c(0.5,0.5,0.4,0.4))
r10 <- setValues(r, c(0.22,0.18,0.3,0.25))
r11 <- setValues(r, c(0.1,0.4,0.3,0.3))
r12 <- setValues(r, c(0.4,0.5,0.3,0.4))

# 1st Stack
s <- c(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11,r12)

#and some other variables:
temp <- c(2.3,2.1,2.2,3,3.5,5,5.6,7,10,8,3,1)
rain <- c(0,0,50,100,0,0,170,0,250,150,0,0)

# 2 more Stacks just like 1st stack s with NA values
SM1 <- EA <- s
SM1[] <- EA[] <-NA

# Value 1 inserted at different positions as a starting point for calculations to 
# begin for individual cells. As stack has 4 cells per layer and each cell has 
# different starting point in time. Each layer represent a month so 12 layers for a year.
SM1[1][4:12] <- 1
SM1[2][3:12] <- 1
SM1[3][5:12] <- 1
SM1[4][2:12] <- 1

f <- function(x){
# find index of point from where calculations should begin
st <- which(x == 1)
# fill SM[st+1] with calculated value
x[st+1] <- rain[st+1]/temp[st+1]
# Now this is tricky, how to apply this? EA stack gets filled with some other calculated value
EA[st] <- x[st]/(temp[st]-rain[st])
# Return both x and EA 
x
EA
}

SM <- app(SM1,f)
```

So, this is a minimum reproducible example of something complex I am trying to do. I am avoiding for loops but stack SM gets calculated and then stack EA gets filled. If 5th cell of stack SM is getting filled, 4rth cell of EA stack gets filled and so on.

Is it possible to do something like this in app function or maybe another method. Alternatively, I join both stacks using cbind and write function which runs to the nlyr of individual stacks and using indices to fill other like:

```
C <- cbind(SM,EA)
C[i] <- calculations....
C[nlyr(SM) + i -1] <- calculations....
```